# Which versions of python3 can we use with current QGIS3 version

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, installation, macos

Mac OS 10.04, QGIS 3.10.

I have been a way from QGIS for a while and I am now setting up a "new" Mac and having my usual battle with python.  Great to see that we now have signed package for QGIS but are we still constrained to using python 3.6.5?

Mac Os now installs 3.7 by default and I would rather not have to learn about virtual environments if I don't need to!  (But I fear I will ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of (at least) QGIS 3.10 it is no longer dependent on python 3.6.5!

It took me quite a while to actually verify this but looking through Preferences->System->Current env vars you find
`PYTHONHOME => /Applications/QGIS3.10.app/.../Versions/Current`

and listing this gives:

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 rful011 <snip> /Applications/QGIS3.10.app/.../Current -> 3.7
```

One thing that confused me thoroughly even after I had established that it was using 3.7 was that my scripts (run from Script Runner) did not find the the modules that I had installed with pip.  It turns out that pip was installing them in `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages` but this was not in the QGIS's python path.

Once I added this to the path in the script it worked but as I soon discovered this is not a good solution.  The reason being that this ties the script to a particular machine.  I run QGIS on 3 different macs and depending on subtleties that currently elude python installed the modules in different places.

One thing I discovered is that QGIS installs its own version of python within the application and I am pretty sure this is why the sys.path does not include the normal site-packages directory

Answer (score 0):

OsGeo4W installs Python 3.7.0 so I conclude there is no technical reason why you shouldn't be able to use 3.6 or 3.7 with QGIS - in fact I assume soon we will be encouraged to upgrade

Comment: that is for windows, yes?.  Until recently the Mac OS builds of QGIS 3 mandated python 3.6.5.  I am trying to check if this is still the case given that some other things have changed with the Mac OS builds and the new installer say nothing about python requirements